# Set up a new hard drive for Playstation 3?

Tags: ps3

I have a new PS3 hard drive.  I put  the 4.80 software on a USB flash drive then in my ps3 but it won't read it. Is there any way I can formatted my hard drive for my PS3?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the System Software on the HDD by using the Safe Mode. To access the Safe Mode, follow this steps:

- Turn off the console (make sure that the indicator light is red).
- Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds, until the console turn itself off.
- Release the power button.
- Press and hold the power button until you hear two short beeps, then release the button.
- Connect your controller via USB and press the PS button.

You should be able to see this screen:

[image: Safe Mode Options]

Select the option called "Restore PS3 System" (number 5), and you will be asked to insert an USB with the System Software:

**NOTE**: If "Restore PS3 System" does not work, select "System Update" and try again.

[image: Restore PS3 System]

You can get this file and instructions on [Sony's Website](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps3/).

Once you have inserted the USB drive, press Start and Select at the same time.

If everything went OK, you should see the following:

[image: Installing]

Now just wait for the process to complete, this will take between 5 to 20 minutes.

At the end, you should see the welcome screen for the PS3.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to format the hard drive to a FAT32 on the PC first before you can use it on the PS3.

Comment: The PS3 formats the hard drive if is not recognized by the console, asking for the most recent software. Thurs, doing a FAT32 format on the PC is a waste of time.